# configure gitlab as remote repository in artifactory

Tags: artifactory

I would like to configure a gitlab repository as a remote repository in artifactory. I can see in  the list of VCS github but not gitlab. Is this configuration possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This Artifactory ticket suggests that perhaps it's not (currently) possible... [VCS Remote Repo should support Gitlab EE](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-8530)